# Is there minimum clearance from gas stove to door?

Tags: kitchens, code-compliance, safety, stove

I know there is a minimum clearance to hood and cabinets above, but I can't find a side-clearance to a doorway.

My concern is someone coming through the door and not seeing the hot stove around the corner.

Edit: it's an interior door. I'm not concerned with drafts, I'm concerned with safety.

Comment: I have never heard of any clearance requirement between a stove and an open passageway.

Comment: An aunt of mine had a smallish, modest house with the stove right by a doorway and there never seems to be a problem.

Comment: The potential problem with a gas stove is draft. There may be other ways to deal with the problem.  I understand why OP is asking, my great grandfather has a gas stove next to the kitchen door, in a 120 year old house, which he can’t open while cooking unless it’s dead still outside.

Comment: @Tyson will strong air currents blow out the gas flame?

Comment: @JimStewart yes, pilot light as well.

Comment: Have you looked up the particular brand in Google, or do you have the original manual?  There may be some guidance available.  Beyond that, though, it seems your question is based on common sense .  Your gut could well be telling you the right thing to do.  Especially with regards the normal functioning of the stove.  imho, if there are air currents that prevent it from working perfectly then it would seem to follow that mounting elsewhere would be the best approach.

Comment: The OP here has not said whether the doorway adjacent to the stove was an inside one or an outside one, nor whether his stove is gas or electric. In my aunt's house the gas stove was located adjacent to a  door into the kitchen from the living room.

Comment: @JimStewart “gas” is in the title.  I admit I missed OPs last sentence somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no code requirement in the IRC specifying minimum distance between stove and doorway.

Doesn’t make it a good idea, but it’s not banned.

http://www.inspectionnews.net/home_inspection/built-in-appliances-and-systems-home-inspection-and-commercial-inspection/21577-range-distance-door.html